# Placing image inside a div in HTML 5

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

My simple `div` element is as below:

```
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="http://quickshare.my3gb.com/download/testpic.jpg" />
</div>
```

**(The original image is 216 * 216 pixels)**
and my CSS is as follows,

```
.avatar {
float: right;
border: 1px #ccc solid;
width: 70px;
height: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}
```

And the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/BMU4Y/2/

The question is, I cannot get the image to fit on the div within which it resides.

Any help would be much appreciated. [I also tried for a jquery image-resizer, but could not find anything that really works :( ]

Kindly note this is for my HTML 5 website being built with C# and MVC 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overflow is not needed here. And to make the image fit the div, it should have 100% heigh and width.

```
.avatar {
float: left;
border: 1px #ccc solid;
width: 70px;
height: 80px;
position: relative;
}
.avatar img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BMU4Y/3/

Comment: I don't think the `height` property needs to be set, I guess it's auto by default and if the `width` is set to `100%` the height should scale based on the taken width. +1 though

Comment: @larssy1: Thanks. Worked like a charm. My question is, obviously this seems to be working, but why people write re-sizing scripts? What is the purpose of them ?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The floating was in the context of the person that asked the Question. I suppose that float was their for a purpose which fits his layout.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. I actually have no idea. It might be that the actual measurements are preserved.

Comment: @KristerAndersson Please check the jsfiddle and try to delete a value. You WILL see a difference. Which means he is not fitting the entire div.

Comment: @larssy1 - Yes, you're completely right. But, still using the `height:auto` would be better (my opinion) because when using `height:100%` the image might get distorted depending on the actual dimensions. Of course the question was "how to fit the image inside the entire div", so that doesn't matter, really

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. Coming back to your question why people make resize scripts, I remember a time I created a PhotoViewer application for a school task. I also created such a kind of resizer to make sure the distortions mentioned above didn't happen. Like, if the height is larger then the width, then the photo should be sized on its height, not width, but if the photo's width is larger then its height, it should be determined on its width instead of height.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
.avatar {
float: left;
border: 1px #ccc solid;
width: 70px;
height: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.avatar img {
max-width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add at .css file

```
.avatar img{
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right in understanding that you want the image to fit within your explicitly sized div, then adding the following to your css will make it work:

```
.avatar img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  .avatar 
    {
        float: left;
        border: 1px #ccc solid;
        overflow: hidden;
        width:60px;
        height:60px;
    }

    .avatar img {
        width:inherit;
        height:inherit
    }
```

Comment: about the `inherit` ? Does the image automatically resizes to 60 * 60 ?

Comment: If you change the height of the avatar div to 100 and 100 the image resizes to 100, so yeah, the image scales with the width and height of the div.

Comment: +1. thanks. So, i assume, as the other poster say, both `width:inherit` and `width:100%` does the same job?

Comment: The `width:100%` fills the parent div, where as the `inherit` just takes over the width of the parent div. The result is the same

Answer (score 1):

```
.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

You need the image to be in display block and not inline which is by default.
Then give it 100% width (of its parent width), but for the height I've set it in auto. Not 100% because it will stretch it in both dimensions usually with strange results.

Comment: Thanks for that. But, what is the significance of setting it to `block` ? (Sorry, if this is a silly question, I am new and trying to understand)

Comment: Block elements, can have dimensions, margins, paddings etc. These are elements for building purposes. Inline elements are for presentation mostly. Like texts, etc. I suggested the display: block, to be safe, because I don't know what else you have in your css code before that. Also by making display block img tags you can fix some annoying gaps like margin from below your images.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit the width and height of div to Image. Add below CSS and it will work like charm.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BMU4Y/8/

```
.avatar {
float: left;
border: 1px #ccc solid;
width: 70px;
height: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
div.avatar img
{
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit
}
```